# Differences in Factor Analysis Implementations in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, factor-analysis

There are several implementations of factor analysis in Python. The following code returns the loadings obtained with three of these methods:

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

# THE DATA:
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
scaler = StandardScaler()
iris = scaler.fit_transform(iris.iloc[:,:-1])

NUM_COMPONENTS = 1

# METHOD 1:
from sklearn.decomposition import FactorAnalysis
fa1 = FactorAnalysis(n_components=NUM_COMPONENTS, svd_method='lapack', rotation=None)
_ = fa1.fit_transform(iris).flatten()
fa1.components_.T

# METHOD 2:
from factanal.wrapper import factanal
fa2 = factanal(iris, factors=NUM_COMPONENTS, scores='regression', rotation='none', verbose=True, return_dict=True)
fa2['loadings']

# METHOD 3:
from factor_analyzer.factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
fa3 = FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=NUM_COMPONENTS, rotation=None, method='ml')
_ = fa3.fit_transform(iris)
fa3.loadings_
```

With one factor (i.e. `NUM_COMPONENTS = 1`), all three methods return the same loadings (ignoring sign differences). However, increasing the number of factors leads to different results. Method 2 throws an error because the degrees of freedom is negative, and the loadings for Methods 1 and 3 are very different.

Does anyone have any insight into why this is the case? Does it have to do with the negative degrees of freedom, or is it simply a difference in the optimisation procedure?

**Note:** If you replace the iris data with random data (`np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(150,5)` using `np.random.seed(12345)`), Methods 2 and 3 return the same loadings when `NUM_COMPONENTS` is 1 or 2 (+ve d.o.f), but these are different to those returned by Method 1. So it seems like the `sklearn` implementation *sometimes* returns different results to the other two methods, even with one factor. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the link about Method1:scikit-learn package is useful: [Factor Analysis Scikit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291969/factor-analysis-scikit). "A simple linear generative model with Gaussian latent variables." In case of Method 3 from factor_analyzer, it "performs exploratory and factor analysis (EFA), with several optional rotations. It also includes a class to perform confirmatory factor analysis (CFA), with certain pre-defined constraints. "
When I conduct my dataset in these two methods, it really makes big differences. I think the main difference is based on the assumption whether the data is Gaussian distribution or not.